# Spring 3.2 -- 404 error calling a controller method from a link in a JSP

Tags: spring-mvc, hyperlink, controller, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to use a link in my JSP to pass a parameter to a method in my Spring controller, but I get a 404 error.  Here is the relevant part of my JSP code.

```
<c:forEach var="bulletin" items="${bulletins}">
    <c:if test="${bulletin.approved}">
        <a href="/bulletin/${bulletin.id}" >${bulletin.name}
            -- ${bulletin.subject}</a>
        <br />
        <br />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Here is the method in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bulletin/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSingleBulletin(@PathVariable("id") int id,
        Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    try {
        Bulletin bulletin = bulletinDAO.getSingleBulletin(id);
        mav.setViewName("WEB-INF/jsp/ShowBulletin");
        if (bulletin != null) {
            ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                    .currentRequestAttributes();
            HttpSession session = attributes.getRequest().getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("bulletin", bulletin);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        mav.setViewName("WEB-INF/jsp/FailurePage");
    }

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: What's the context path of the webapp? Is it the root webapp?

Comment: What about changing the a href tag with the following

<a href="<c:url value="/getSingleBulletin/${bulletin.id}" />">${bulletin.name}</a>

Comment: @blackpanther I just tried your solution, and it didn't work.  I just got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  Here is my URL.

```
<a href="<c:url value="/bulletin/${bulletin.id}" />" >${bulletin.name} -- ${bulletin.subject}</a>
```

Here is my controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bulletin/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSingleBulletin(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        try {
            Bulletin bulletin = bulletinDAO.getSingleBulletin(id);
            model.addAttribute("bulletin", bulletin);
            return "ShowBulletin";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return "FailurePage";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is path problem.

Check path of the controller which contains the 'getSingleBulletin' function in question.
Is that set as root path?(/)
If it isn't that is the reason.

For example,

```
/* path to below controller */
@RequestMapping("/toController")  
public class TheController {

  /* path to below function (in the controller) */
  @RequestMapping(value="getSingleBulletin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView getSingleBulletin(/*parameters*/) {

  }

}
```

In this case if you want to send a request to 'getSingleBulletin' function, you have to set  the path in anchor tag as

```
<a href="/toController/getSingleBulletin?id=${bulletin.id}">${bulletin.name} -- ${bulletin.subject}</a>
```

---

If the path to controller is not  root('/') and set the path in anchor tag without 'controller path' just like your code

```
<a href="/getSingleBulletin?id=${bulletin.id}">${bulletin.name} -- ${bulletin.subject}</a>
```

Spring MVC try to find a controller which has RequetMapping to '/getSingleBulletin', which results 404 error(if such controller is not defined), not the function 'getSingleBulletin' in 'TheController'.

I hope this will help you : )

Comment: Eclipse is complaining about the value attribute -- it seems that <a> doesn't have it.  I've searched on Google and can't find another attribute to use.  Any clues out there?

Comment: Oh... value attribute is just example, I didn't check for 'value'. The important part is just 'href' attribute.

Comment: Yes, I see that you updated your response.  But I still have a parameter to pass to my method.  How do I do it?

Comment: I still don't see where to put my parameter in the a href.  I'm going to have several bulletins in a list, and my method needs to know which one I want to get.

Comment: If you want to pass parameter to the method, you can pass it just like what you did first. <a href="/toController/getSingleBulletin?id=${Bulletin.id}">Click</a>

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work.  I have refactored my code to use another approach, and that didn't work either.  My original post has been changed to reflect it.

Comment: Check your web.xml file in spring project and find 'servlet-mapping'. Is 'url-pattern' set as   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   ??? If it is, change it to   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>   Just one slash without asterisk mark.

Comment: That's what I currently have for url-pattern.